# Swift Image Cache not Reloading

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having problems cacheing for images from JSON correctly with this UIImageView extension. The images load correctly when I first open the app and scroll down the page. However when I scroll back up, they don't reload and are completely gone. Can anyone see anything wrong with the code?

```
   let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

   extension UIImageView   {

    func loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: String) {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage   {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "URLSession error")
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)

                self.image = imageToCache
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is the snippet from the cell.swift file

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

func setupThumbnailImage() {
    if let thumbnailImageUrl = television?.poster_url   {

        let urlPrefix = "https://www.what-song.com"
        let urlSuffix = thumbnailImageUrl

        let urlCombined = urlPrefix + urlSuffix

        thumbnailImageView.loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: urlCombined)

    }
}
```

Comment: How does your `cellforrowatindexpath` method look?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **`kingFisher`**, it is very easy to use and it manages all starting from cache threads etc.

```
           let imageResource = ImageResource(downloadURL:URL(string: imagePath )!,cacheKey: imagePath )
           viewImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity
           viewImage.kf.setImage(with: resource)
```

where `imagePath` is the url of your image and viewImage is your imageView

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer, since it only indirectly fixes the problem. OP might have reasons (legal, technical etc.) for not being able to use external libs in this case.

Comment: Just provide a link to the KingFisher repo on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you would be calling it in wrong way. 
Remember that in tableView you reuse the cells. 
By the time response comes back for the URLSessionTask you would have already scrolled up/down. In that case `self.image` would be assigned to the currently visible cell. 
Please add your cellForRow code in question.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I have added the snippet from the cell swift file, is that what you need?